# How I can use variable as field name in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

It is possible to make something like this in Postgres?

```
DECLARE variable VARCHAR  
BEGIN  
    variable := TG_RELNAME || '_id';  
    OLD.variable = 123;  
END;
```

I can't use value of variable as field_name...

p.s. my version of db is 8.4.

Comment: no, this trigger is for delete row. `DELETE FROM alerts WHERE item_table = TG_RELNAME AND item_id = OLD.{field_name_from_variable_value}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to make an extra query, for example

```
execute 'update ' || TG_RELNAME || ' set ' || variable ||' = 123';
```

Comment: Note, this is probably a bad idea (it will lead to extra bloat or race conditions). There are some work around like using non-plpgsql trigger functions, but probably the thing to do is to just hard code the functions.

Comment: You should quote `TG_RELNAME` and `variable` using the `quote_ident()` function to avoid syntax errors if they contain "unusual" characters: `execute 'update ' || quote_ident(TG_RELNAME) || ' set ' || quote_ident(variable) ||' = 123';`